# If performance is an very important consideration, is it good to consider c++0x?

Tags: c++, testing, c++11

I wrote a simple test to check how good c++0x is. Here is the sample C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
 #define emplace_back push_back
 #define auto typeof(vs.begin())
#endif
int main()
{
 vector<string> vs;
 string s;
 while(cin>>s)
 {
  vs.emplace_back(s);
 }
 sort(vs.begin(),vs.end());
 for(auto it = vs.begin();it != vs.end();++it)
 {
  cout << (*it) << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Here is a script to run it

```
#!/bin/bash

inputFile=`mktemp`;
outputFile1=`mktemp`
outputFile2=`mktemp`

cat /dev/urandom | base64 > $inputFile 2> /dev/null &

echo "Generating Sample Input.. ${1:-10} seconds"
sleep ${1:-10}

export TOKILL=`pgrep -P $$ cat`
$(kill $TOKILL) 2> /dev/null > /dev/null

wc -l $inputFile
echo -e "\nTesting without --std=gnu++0x"
g++ Test.C -o old
time ./old < $inputFile > $outputFile1

echo -e "\nTesting with --std==gnu++0x"
g++ Test.C --std=gnu++0x -o new
time ./new < $inputFile > $outputFile2

diff $outputFile1 $outputFile2
rm $inputFile $outputFile1 $outputFile2
```

Most of the time I tested, C++03 proves better than c++0x. 
Here is a sample output.

```
Generating Sample Input.. 10 seconds
845645 /tmp/tmp.YMxZtrVeD0

Testing without --std=gnu++0x

real 0m12.437s
user 0m10.273s
sys 0m2.152s

Testing with --std==gnu++0x

real 0m12.452s
user 0m10.241s
sys 0m2.196s
```

c++ code is self explanatory.
Script generates random strings of equal length seperated by a newline in a temporary file.  Number of lines in the generated file is printed.

I'm using vector and sort. Sort will use std::swap. With rvalue references, and std::move, isn't the code supposed to work faster?

My g++ version is 
`g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5`
Ok. I'll reword my Question.
If performance is an very important consideration, is it good to consider c++0x? 
If the way I conducted the test is wrong, how should I do it correctly to find the answer myself.
Please provide some examples.

Comment: Clearly hand-crafted assembler is better than C++03 so why are you even asking this irrelevant question?

Comment: C++0x is (will be soon) a standard. You are testing an implementation... So your title is not well chosen.

Comment: how is c++03 proved that "better" ? i can't see any difference.

Comment: @David: I don't see the relevance (and it often isn't true either). If a language is updated with several performance-enhancing features, and you write a test relying on those features which turns out to be no faster, then asking this question makes good sense.

Comment: @jalf C++0x is about performance? Really?

Comment: Voted to close. This is not a question.

Comment: @David: rvalue references are.

Comment: @Konrad: Not necessarily. Move semantics are faster than copy semantics, but they're also new valid semantics in their own right. See things like `std::unique_ptr` for where move semantics are a big deal without being a big deal in performance.

Comment: @David: yes. That's the prime motivation for rvalue references. Everything in C++ is about performance to some extent (even if it's just "it must be *fast enough*, or "not unnecessarily slow"), but rvalue references are definitely about performance. And even if that wasn't the main goal of rvalue refs, it'd still be an expected side effect, and so it'd still be a meaningful question to ask.

Comment: @David Not only about Performance but still performance is one of the important aspects of it. isnt it?
Here I compare the performance of the same code with compiler from same implementor. Not an assembly code with equivalent c++ code.

Comment: `string s = new char[78];`?  What the hell is the point of that?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the question to "How do I do a performance test for what(if any) enhancement is offered by C++0x rvalue references?"

Comment: Here is how you do it: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.libstdc%2B%2B.devel/22187

Comment: @PigBen Sorry, It was a typho, Even without it, the result doesnt change much.

Answer (score 10):

This is totally fail. What you've done here:

- Initialize an `std::string` from an uninitialized chunk of characters allocated on the heap. Completely undefined behavior and leaks like hell.
- Call `emplace_back(someotherstdstring)`, thereby *still copying a std::string*.

What you probably really wanted to do is `emplace_back(somecharptr)` but even then this would be totally fail. There isn't going to be any real difference of just doing

```
std::string s0("foo"); // emplace_back("foo")
std::string s1(s0); // emplace_back(s0)
std::string s2((std::string const&)s0); // push_back(s0)
```

Arguably, the construction from `s0` is even more performant because `s0` already knows the length of the string, while the length of `"foo"` first has to be calculated by the constructor of `std::string`.

I recommend to first think through all you have written there. The whole point of `emplace_back` is to avoid constructing an object just to pass it to `push_back` and copy it. But in your case *you already have an object* so it doesn't really make sense to pass it through `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 5):

Uh, you changed to emplace_back and then emplace_back'd an lvalue? That's not going to make any difference- it's still an lvalue and you're still making a copy. In C++03 then std::string will almost certainly use a swap that's just as good as rvalue references- move semantics are just much more generic. Modern Standard libraries already use something called swaptimization for certain classes that mimics the effect of rvalue references under certain conditions, including vector resizing.

Bottom line: You've picked the most heavily optimized, specialized and focused code in the entire C++ world. This code has effectively already had move semantics applied to it under the hood and you don't use any actual rvalues anywhere. How are rvalue references going to make any difference?

Comment: Ok. If this code is heavily optimised. Please suggest me some cases where its not optimised and i can observe the difference.

Comment: @balki: That's not the question. However, you could return a complex class, `vector<vector<string>>`, say, by value from a function where RVO/NRVO cannot be applied.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't see where C++03 is "better". Your timings are close enough together that I'd say it's a tie. And your benchmarking code is flawed. What you're timing is mainly I/O because your input/output code is included in the benchmark.

Second, C++0x allows some *potential* performance improvements. But it doesn't guarantee anything, and it relies on the standard library to actually take advantage of this throughout.

Finally, through RVO and copy elision (and `std::swap`), unnecessary copies can often be avoided in C++03, even without rvalue references. But rvalue references generalizes this, and allows similar optimizations to be applied in far more cases than was possible in C++03